# problem installing rhythmbox v3 on 13.10

Tags: apt, rhythmbox

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/jacob/media/ubuntu/ saucy/main rhythmbox amd64 3.0.1-1ubuntu5~ppa0
  Connection failed
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/jacob/media/ubuntu/ saucy/main rhythmbox-mozilla amd64 3.0.1-1ubuntu5~ppa0
  Connection failed
```

This is the error I get when i try to install rhythmbox v3. What should i do?

Below is the output of `apt-cache policy rhythmbox`

```
rhythmbox: Installed: (none) Candidate: 3.0.1-1ubuntu5~ppa0 Version table: 
3.0.1-1ubuntu5~ppa0 0 500 ppa.launchpad.net/jacob/media/ubuntu saucy/main amd64 Packages 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status 
3.0-1~ppafossfreedomubuntu7 0 500 ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/rhythmbox/ubuntu saucy/main amd64 Packages 
2.99.1-0ubuntu1 0 500 in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy/main amd64 Packages
```

Output of `sudo apt-get install rhythmbox`

```
Err ppa.launchpad.net/jacob/media/ubuntu saucy/main rhythmbox amd64 3.0.1-1ubuntu5~ppa0 Connection failed 0% [Waiting for headers]
```

I tried removing the PPA, and after that I ran `sudo apt-get install rhyhmbox`. 
Now its showing this.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
rhythmbox : Depends: librhythmbox-core8 (= 3.0-1~ppafossfreedomubuntu7) but 3.0.1-1ubuntu5~ppa0 is to be installed 
Depends: rhythmbox-data (= 3.0-1~ppafossfreedomubuntu7) but it is not going to be installed 
Recommends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly but it is not going to be installed 
Recommends: rhythmbox-plugins but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?   This is the next line after the above error msg.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: did that. not working

Comment: Did you have an working internet connection?

Comment: yes the internet was working

Comment: You already added foss's PPA. Try this command only `sudo apt-get install rhythmbox`

Comment: I tried that. still not working

Comment: And then try to install rhythmbox.

Comment: post the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did, and it works.  Remove any previous installations, and any plug-ins.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:fossfreedom/rhythmbox
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:jacob/media
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get purge rhythmbox rhythmbox-plugins
```

Then use this PPA to install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jacob/media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox
```

See image below:

[image]